# Iterate over XML "cousins" with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have the below XML document stored in a TSQL variable with `XML` type:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child>Alice</child>
    <child>Bob</child>
    <child>Carol</child>
  </parent>
  <house>
    <room><id>1</id></room>
    <room><id>2</id></room>
    <room><id>3</id></room>
  </house>
</root>
```

I would like to iterate over "cousin" nodes (that is, nodes whose parents are siblings) and insert in a table one row per iteration and one column per cousin. So the result would be something like this:

```
Child | Room
------------
Alice | 1
Bob   | 2
Carol | 3
```

(I know for a fact that there are as many rooms as children).

I feel like this is a simple task, but can't seem to find a way. I am a beginner in SQL Server and XPath, and probably lack the terminology to look for documentation.

What I've tried so far is to iterate over, say the `child` elements, and try to read the matching `room` element from there using `ROW_NUMBER` to pick the room I want:

```
INSERT INTO children (child, room)
SELECT 
  child = T.Item.value('(../parent/child/text())[' + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.Item)) + ']', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
  room = T.Item.value('(id/text())[1]', 'CHAR(1)')
FROM   
  @XML.nodes('root/house/room') AS T(Item)
```

But SQL server complains that the `value()` accepts only string literal as first argument (what kind of limitation is that??).

Any idea of how I could do that simply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this the best or shortest way, but it produces the output you require:

```sql
DECLARE @x XML='
<root>
  <parent>
    <child>Alice</child>
    <child>Bob</child>
    <child>Carol</child>
  </parent>
  <house>
    <room><id>1</id></room>
    <room><id>2</id></room>
    <room><id>3</id></room>
  </house>
</root>';

;WITH childs AS (
    SELECT
        n.e.value('.','NVARCHAR(128)') AS child,
        id=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
        @x.nodes('/root/parent/child') AS n(e)
),
room_ids AS (
    SELECT
        n.e.value('.','NVARCHAR(128)') AS room_id,
        id=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
        @x.nodes('/root/house/room/id') AS n(e)
)
SELECT
    c.child,
    r.room_id
FROM
    childs AS c
    INNER JOIN room_ids AS r ON
        r.id=c.id
ORDER BY
    c.id;
```

Comment: Typically the sort of solution I was thinking of but could not express because of my poor skills in SQL :) I was hoping something simpler, but it works indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As a pure XPath query you might do this:

```
SELECT The.Room.value('id[1]','varchar(max)'),The.Room.value('let $r:=. return (../../parent/child[position()=$r]/text())[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM @YourXML.nodes('/root/house/room') AS The(Room)
```

But - to be honest - I'd prefer TT.'s solution. This solution relys on the rooms to be numbered from 1 to n without gaps. TT.'s solution would work even with unsorted room numbers...

Comment: upvote because I learnt something that me be useful later, but indeed in my real data the rooms may not even be numbered.